# Setting up a Server-side interpreter

Tags: php, interpreter, server-side

OK. So, let's take PHP as an example.

- I'm entering a URL in the browser, requesting a php script. (e.g. `http://www.somedomain.com/index.php`)
- The browser *sends that request* to the appropriate server.
- The server *recognizes* - by its extension (`.php`) - that's it's a PHP
  file.
- The PHP interpreter *processes the file* and outputs the results.
- The server *sends back the output*.

Now, let's say we are dealing with a... home-made interpreter XYZ (with its binary,etc), dealing e.g. with `.xyz` files.

How should I go about that, so all the above things are valid for my XYZ interpreter?

**How should I set this whole thing up, so that it works properly?**

---

***Hint :*** I'm not requesting help on how to write an interpreter, but on how to make it function the above way...

Comment: Start by reading your webserver's documentation on how to add a new 'handler' for whatever file type you want. Other than that, your question can't be answered. The browser is irrelevant in this, since you're dealing with purely server-side code.

Comment: You need to configure Apache or whatever webserver to tell them "Hey, here's a new language, XYZ, here is how you interpret it, and use XYZ with files ending in .xyz". It's not easy task.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem very clear. Is the interpreter PHP-compatible, webserver software, or some Apache/other addon?
I'm guessing it outputs HTML like PHP does?

Comment: @user1015599 It's about a basic interpreter I myself have written; and I'd simply like to start testing it like a web-scripting language/interpreter...

Comment: The combination of the first two comments above, (with the exception of the "...can't be answered" portion) would make a good answer. If one assumes that Apache is your HTTP server then you'd place an AddHander line to your .htaccess file. I did a search to see how you'd pipe your output back to apache and found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772400/how-does-php-interface-with-apache It might be helpful for not only getting the output back to apache, but in gettng all the headers and such into your parser.

Comment: @TecBrat I'm having a look at it right now; thanks!

Comment: You can use virtually any scripting interpreter. In the simplest of cases just utilize it as `CGI` interpreter by making the script executable and giving it a standard `.cgi` extension. With a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/awk` you can utilize it. (Configuring specific extensions to behave that way is step 2, most simply with a RewriteRule even.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on what web server you are using. However, if that is Apache, you should look into `apxs` for building and installing your own apache modules. Google will help you find online tutorials on `apxs`.

For adding a handler for a specific file ending, you should do something like this in your apache configuration (after your iterpreter/apache module is built):

```
AddHandler my_handler .end
```

Comment: I just want to add one thing... You can do it the CGI or FastCGI way too, but: If you want street cred / geek cred, building your own module with apxs is awesomeiest!!!.!!:!.!:!!

Answer (score 2):

Your options are to either use an existing, standard interface and write your software to conform to it, or to write a new module for the server.

For the former, [CGI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) is simple but inefficient while [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html) is more modern but relatively complicated.

If you want to write a new module, then the specifics will depend on the server you are dealing with.